# Disable remote transfer in Total Commander

Tags: ftp, total-commander

I want to copy files between two FTP servers without creating a temporary copy on my own computer and **without initiating a remote transfer**. I expect Total Commander to read data from one FTP server and write it to the other. But it gets smart and tries to negotiate a remote transfer between the FTP servers which fails with `Remote transfer failed - probable NOT supported by server!`

Is there any setting / tweak / trick that disables remote transfer in TC?

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  You don't want to create a temporary copy and you also don't want to initiate a remote transfer.  You have elminated both methods for transfering a file.  If you want to reading data from one FTP server and write to another, what you just described, is a remote transfer.

Comment: @Ramhound No. Remote transfer is when one FTP server connects to the other. Temporary copy is a temporary file on local storage. Reading from source to memory and then writing from memory to target (in chunks) is what a classic local copy does and a copy from one FTP server to the other could do.

Comment: The simplest way would be to ssh into the one server, then copy from the other server to the first one.

Comment: I don't necessarily have SSH access to those servers. For example web hosting often comes with web upload/download and FTP, but not with SSH.

Comment: You could open both ftp sites in two instances of Windows Explorer and copy the file(s) from one to the other. This will use the same method as local copy through local memory.

Comment: @harrymc It's a nice workaround.

Comment: Glad you like it. I added an answer with more details.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple method for copying files between FTP sites
while using the standard Windows copy which copies files using
the local memory buffers :

> Open both ftp sites in two instances of Windows Explorer and copy the file(s)
>   from one to the other.

When specifying the FTP site in Explorer,
the user-name and password must be included as follows :
`ftp://<user name>:<password>@<ftp_site_address>`.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you can *not* achieve in TC.

I'm sorry for the bad news :(

**Just a thought** - You mentioned hosting.

If there is PHP available, you may be able to use PHP Pear's inbuilt FTP functionality to sync between those two hosted instances

https://pear.php.net/package/Net_FTP